# How to perform incremental refresh on merged table?

Tags: powerbi

I have 2 tables in Power query editor.

I want to merge them and implement incremental load on merged table.

Following is my plan:

Merge both tables into a new table (Table3)

Disable refresh and disable load for both tables.

How to configure Incremental refresh on Table3?

Do I need to also configure Incremental refresh on Table1 and Table2?

So technically- will each table get incrementally loaded and then merge. Or will entire data be merged and then incrementally loaded?

Answer (score 2):

For this to work you need to, in simple terms:

- Create your limiting parameters `RangeStart` and `RangeEnd`
- Set up a filter on applicable date columns using `RangeStart` and `RangeEnd` parameters for your subqueries `Table 1` and `Table 2` (this controls data ingestion)
- Set up the same type logic for the applicable date column in `Table 3` (this controls data deletion)
- Configure incremental refresh time logic

For it to be actually efficient you also need to make sure:

- Data is transactional in nature
- Both subqueries are foldable and from the same data source
- The resulting table is foldable

If the queries are not foldable, it will require a full data load and subsequent filter anyway, removing the benefits of incremental refresh.

There exists a nice write-up of this in the [Power BI Community pages](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Community-Blog/Incremental-Refresh-with-Subqueries/ba-p/1003337) that details how you would go about setting this up for a header/detail table join.

Comment: What is the point of setting up the parameters on Table1 and Table2 when incremental refresh can only be configured on Table3?

Comment: The point is to limit the data being queried and loaded. This is what limiting data ingestion refers to. I suggest you read the linked article too, since it discusses things a bit more in depth.

Comment: Thanks. But when we disable load and refresh on Table1 and Table2, and enable incremental on Table3, doesn't that by itself limit data being queried and loaded?

Comment: Technically table 1 and table 2 are only used for merging which gives table 3. Now when I turn off enable load and refresh on table 1 and table 2 then those tables won't refresh or load anyways. So am I right to say we need incremental refresh configured only on table 3?

Comment: I think your reasoning is correct IF the resultant `Table 3` query is a valid folding query, that folds the entire joining SQL expression to the database.